# Oven has 2-prong plug plus earth wire. Socket is modern 3-prong. How to connect?

Tags: grounding, oven, cables, cord-and-plug

My 110V toaster oven has a 2-prong cable. Also, the oven's chassis has a screw with a connected green/yellow earth wire, which I want to ground.

My wall socket is a modern 3-prong with earth and all.

Is there a special adapter that can convert the 2-prong plug + earth wire into a 3-prong plug? Is that the right way to go?

Thank you![image: Back side of toaster oven]

Comment: Pictures would help. But, you could replace the entire wire with a newer wire similar to a power tool cord replacement.

Comment: Can you get a new cord and strain-relief for the toaster oven?

Comment: Without actually seeing the problem it is impossible to say what the best solution is, although the above 2 comments seem to be your best bet. However, if you are not confident doing this sort of modification it is best left to someone who is,or you may end up as the toast!

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I've added a photo of the back side of the toaster oven.

Comment: Is this thing even UL listed, or did you acquire it off Amazon Marketplace (Sold by xxxxxx and fulfilled by Amazon), or eBay, AliExpress etc. ?   Coz the yellow/green ground wire is a *real bad sign*, it is a redflag for that...

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/39848/japanese-appliance-has-a-green-yellow-ground-wire-coming-out-of-it-what-should

Comment: Do you have the instruction manual that was included with this toaster?  What does it say about how to connect it?

Comment: Also, does the toaster have a square-within-a-square mark anywhere on it?

Answer (score 1):

You could install a replacement three-prong plug and wrap the cable and extra wire with loom to keep them bundled. It's probably not strictly legal, but it's generally safe.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am curious if really need to do that, given that my apartment is equipped with a ground fault circuit interrupter?

Comment: Probably not, but that isn't what you asked.

Comment: So a GFCI is a replacement to grounding?

Comment: Lots of info to be found on that. [1](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/104170/replacing-two-pronged-outlet-with-gfci-not-grounded-is-it-adequate-for-electro), [2](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/121634/is-it-considered-safe-to-connect-ground-to-neutral-with-gfci-outlets), [3](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/91089/is-is-safe-to-only-use-a-gfci-with-no-ground-wires-downstream)

Comment: use braided cable sleeve ... automotive supply store may stock it in different colors ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=braided+cable+sleeve&iax=images&ia=images